# Play WebSocketActor createHandler with custom name

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, akka

I am using (learning to) handle websockets in play application.
My controller is using WebSocket.acceptWithActor

```
def clientWS = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { _ =>
   upstream => ClientSesssionActor.props(upstream)
}
```

and all is well except some other "supervisor" actor needs to be able to use context.actorSelection(...) to communicate with all/some of those ClientSessionActors.

But all my ClientSessionActors are created with a path like this one :

*[akka://application/system/websockets/ REQ_ID /handler]*

Here is the line where WebsocketActorSupervisor creates them :

```
val webSocketActor = context.watch(context.actorOf(createHandler(self), "handler"))
```

That is where the "**handler**" part of the path comes from.

I would like to pass in a specific name for my ClientSessionActor instead of getting "handler".

Overloading the whole call stack with one more parameter seems inelegant: there is WebSocketActor.scala with Connect, WebSocketActorSupervisor(props and constructor), WebSocketsActor receive and then everything inside the WebSocket.scala.

I know I can pass the supervisor reference to the props, but what about the case when the "supervisor" has been restarted and needs to reconnect with his minions.

One more thing, I realize that I might be able to get all the "handler" actors, but there are more than 2 kinds of handlers. Yes I could have them ignore msgs directed at the other groups of handlers but this just feels so redundant sending out 3 times more msgs than I should have to.

Any suggestions ?

James ?  :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about each `ClientSesssionActor` sends a *Register* message to *supervisor* on `preStart` and store them in eg. `val sessions = new HashMap[String, ActorRef]`.

And then unregister by sending *Unregister* in `postStop`

Comment: sure, that is exactly what I did. I just think it's a waste - there is already a perfectly usable actor registry built in and play isn't using it (as far as I could find). So why not let me supply the name. I guess this is addressed more to the Play team and I should post it to that mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class WebSocketsActor extends Actor {
    import WebSocketsActor._

    def receive = {
      case c @ Connect(requestId, enumerator, iteratee, createHandler) =>
        implicit val mt = c.messageType
        context.actorOf(WebSocketActorSupervisor.props(enumerator, iteratee, createHandler),
          requestId.toString)
    }
  }
```

Here is code how play creates actors for handling websockets, it names with requestId. 
I have also same question :) why not make it to name with custom names.